# Ways to handle huge XML/JSON files

Tags: java, android, xml, database, json

I'm looking to create an Android (altho for iOS the problem will be the same) application which will function pretty much as a webshop.

It will contain a lot of products - which can be acces through any way we want since that still has to be build.

The problem is, we created a plain text file to test the size, and it turns out that even a selection of the products, with no structure (XML, JSON..) is already 300mb. 
Once we add a structure, this will logically only cause more overhead and increase this size.

Like I said, pretty much anything is possible in matters of receiving the data.
They can build an API to be able to fetch products once at a time when needed, or 1 big file to parse in a background process...

However, one of the wishes is being (as much as possible) offline. This would normally mean saving all the data into a database on the phone, but if this will result in 300mb on your SD card, this is no good.

To sum it up what I exactly want to know;
Are there any other ways to handle big data like this, without having to keep a connection to internet constantly, or having to download 300mb on someone's phone.

Some kind of compression, special way to save it in the database... any ideas are welcome.

Comment: According to what you gave us, you are going to end up using a lot of space anyway, be it memory, SD etc. You have to save the data on your phone locally since you want to be able to work offline. You could do this in a background process while a user is browsing through a (paginated) list. Only retrieve the data on request if there is an internet connection, if there is not, retrieve whats saved locally. If you want to be upto date with newest content at all time, you are dependand on having a network connection of some kind.

Comment: Hey Joey Roosing,
I do know that i can't get around saving some stuff, either caching or actually saving forever  - and having some kind of an internet connection at some time.
However, my question is more based on how to decrease this amount to a minimum. Perhaps through some compression or something.

Comment: I would have to agree with Joey. Some form of pagination of products e.g. by category or by alphabet or any other natural grouping which makes sense to your product line. These could be stored for a short time locally, if the user went back to a previous selection, so that they didn't need to be re-fetched from the server.

Comment: Compression is an option. In my apps, I use JSON. It is easy to compress, Since it's basically a String you can use gZip(i believe) to compress it, and you can use short names for the keys. For example parent_id would be prnt, doing this 1000 times, also with other keys will save you a hefty amount. JSON has way less overhead then XML. Do note that you trade performance for readability.